# Integral $\int_0^e \left(\operatorname{W}(x)^{2}x-\frac{6x}{8}-\frac{3\operatorname{W}(x)}{8}+\frac{3}{8}\right)\,dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, alternative-proof, lambert-w

Hi I was playing with the Lambert function when I wondering myself about that :

> Prove that  :
>   $$\int_0^e \left(\operatorname{W}(x)^2 x-\frac{6x}{8}-\frac{3\operatorname{W}(x)}{8}+\frac{3}{8} \right) \, dx=0$$

### My try

It's straightforward if we have :

> \begin{align}
> & \int \left(\operatorname{W}(x)^2 x-\frac{6x}{8}-\frac{3\operatorname{W}(x)}{8}+\frac{3}{8} \right) \, dx \\[8pt]
> = {} & \frac{(x (\operatorname{W}(x) - 1) (4 x \operatorname{W}(x)^3 - 3 \operatorname{W}(x)^2 + 3 (x + 1) \operatorname{W}(x) - 3 x))}{(8 \operatorname{W}(x)^2)} \\
> & {} + \text{constant}
> \end{align}

And after using the fundamental theorem of calculus.

### My question

How to prove it using others method?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: other than bring the non-W terms to the right then integrating the left and right, but its no drastically different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the definition of the [Lambert $W$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) we have, taking $W(x)=u\Rightarrow x=ue^u$, that $$\int_0^e W(x)^2 x \, dx = \int_0^1 u^3 e^{2u} (u+1) \, du = \frac{3}{8} (e^2-1)$$ and $$-\frac{3}{8} \int_0^e W(x) \, dx = \int_0^1 ue^u (u+1) \, du = -\frac{3}{8} (e-1)$$ and trivially $$\int_0^e \left(\frac{3}{8}-\frac{6}{8}x\right) \, dx = -\frac{3}{8} (e-1)e.$$

Comment: \left and \right in MathJax, and in LaTeX, can result in proper sizes of delimiters, but in situations like \left(x+1\right) they just complicate the code, where (x+1) would serve just as well. I did some edits here.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You are absolutely right, thank you.